# AngularJS date format not displaying correctly

Tags: angularjs, date, filter, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I have the following code:

```
<td class = "detail_labels"> Date Added: </td>
<td>{{post.issueDate | date: M/d/yyyy}}</td>
```

But it is not showing up as 7/12/2015, it is showing as this: Jul 12, 2015

Please help fix this bug!

Comment: Hmph... shouldn't you put that M/d/yyyy in quotes?

Comment: OMG this is what happens after you program for 7 hours straight on a Sunday, my eyes hurt and I can't think straight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `'` to your filter:

```
<td>{{post.issueDate | date: 'M/d/yyyy'}}</td>
```

See [documentation for date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) on Angular documentation for more information

Comment: It's always so thrilling to post answers/comments on these new questions ;)